# Can a Dispatcher access it's parent Producer methods/attributes?

Tags: elixir, genstage

Can a custom dispatcher made with `@behavior GenStage.Dispatcher` access its parent modules which invokes him as `{:producer, state, dispatcher: CustomDispatcher}` ?

I have realized the dispatcher is launched within the same process than the producer.

If I for example try to launch a `handle_call` from the dispatcher to the producer then I will receive:

```
GenStage.call(producer, :test)                   
** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.1575.0>, :test, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) process attempted to call itself
    (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:917: GenServer.call/3
```

So having this error, is there any other obvious way to access producer's methods?

I know you can initialize the dispatcher with params but I would like to access producer methods/state because they are modified withing producer callbacks

Comment: If you have only one producer, declare the standard interface (like `def foo, do: GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :foo)`) and call it as `MyProducer.foo`.

Comment: When trying MyProducer.foo it complais the the same from the dispatcher: ** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(MyProducer, :foo, 5000) ** (EXIT) process attempted to call itself

Comment: Use `handle_info`, it should be allowed. In general, if you find yourself in a need to call ` the producer from the dispatcher, there is something wrong with a design. It must be abstracted.

Comment: mm I am thinking about using other things, do you know if :ets is shareable between nodes?

Comment: No it is not. `mnesia` is.